# How do I show information attached to a model from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just completed the introduction guide to RoR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. It's a great guide and everything works.

I am trying to extend it a little bit by SHOWING tags in the Post view. (The guide sets it up so that you can add tags while adding a post even though Tag and Post are different models).

This is probably something simple, I just don't know how to do it or find this specific information.

For what it's worth:

```
 <p>
  <b>Tags:</b>
  <%=h @post.tags %>
</p>
```

Shows this:

```
Tags: [#<Tag id: 2, name: "Awesome", post_id: 2, created_at: "2010-02-23 23:53:42", updated_at: "2010-02-23 23:53:42">]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand you right that you get the tag data together with the post data but are unhappy with the display?

I would suggest something like this to make it look nicer:

```
<% @post.tags.each |tag|%>
<%= <span class=tag>tag.name</span> %>
<% end %>
```

Ideally you would wrap this in a partial

_show_tags.html.erb:

```
<% show_tags.each |tag|%>
<%= <span class="tag">tag.name</span> %>
<% end %>
```

and call it with

```
<%= render :partial => show_tags, :collection => @post.tags %>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to comment on your solution, so I comment hear:
Your solution would break if there is more than one tag.

Comment: The guide doesn't really set it up to enter more than one tag, except in string form. I am not going to run with this code, I just wanted to know how to display it. Marking your answer as correct because it provided extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out myself. Should I answer the question myself or vote to close?

Here's the answer anyway:

Go to the posts controller and in the Show action, add this line in:

```
@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
```

This finds the tag needed. Then in the post show view, add this line in:

```
<p>
  <b>Tags:</b>
  <%=h @tag.name %>
</p>
```

This prints the name of the tag.